# XQuery 3.0 and maps in Saxon

Tags: maps, xquery, saxon

I would like to experiment with map features in Saxon (http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/expressions/xpath30maps.xml), but I am unable to get past query compilation. Maybe I am missing some parameter or I use a wrong namespace, but I just can't find the right answer. This is my query code:

```
xquery version "3.0";

(: i have also tried http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map, no difference :)
import module namespace map = "http://ns.saxonica.com/map";

map:get(map { 1 := 'aaa'}, 1)
```

invoked from command line:

```
"c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonEE9.4N\bin\Query.exe" -s:play.xml -q:play2.xq" -qversion:3.0
```

The commands ends with error Cannot locate module for namespace "http://ns.saxonica.com/map" 
When I leave out the module namespace map declaration, the error is Prefix map has not been declared, so I assume it must be.

Comment: I see that the maps feature is only implemented in Saxon 9.4. Have you verified that the version of Saxon you are using is indeed 9.4?

Comment: In case you really have Saxon 9.4, then do have a look at this code example: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/map.xml . Although it is XSLT, you can easily convert it to an equivalent XQuery code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michael Kay has just posted a new blog entry with details on the Saxon Map implementation:
http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2012/01/#000188

Answer (score 2):

You should use `declare namespace` instead of `import module namespace` for access to builtin functions. As far as I understand it, module import is for user-supplied modules only.

File `map.xq`:

```
declare namespace map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
map:get(map { 1 := 'aaa'}, 1)
```

Works just fine:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonEE9.4N\bin\Query.exe" -qversion:3.0 map.xq
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>aaa
```

I tried it with Saxon-EE 9.4.0.2J (the Java version) too, with the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this helps, but the BaseX XQuery Processor also offers an implementation of Michael Kay's map proposal (still to be finalized by the W3): http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Map_Module